# Android studio Gradle not able to reslove dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After creating project in Android-Studio it is stuck at:

```
Gradle: Resolve dependencies 'app:_debugCompile'
```

When I cancel resolve dependencies dialog and try to clean and build project I get

```
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1.
```

In logs Gradle try to find resource in these 2 locations:

```
https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release-bintray/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.pom
```

When I open these url in web browser I see that in both these urls `support` folder does not exist. In which repository support folder is there and how to make `Gradle` look into that repo in which support folder exist?

I have tried number solutions given in 
stackoverflow like updating to latest android support library and support repository, adding proxy in android studio etc. but I am not able to resolve this problem.

How to fix this issue in android studio?

Gradle file in app module-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.anujprashar.newapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Post your gradle file please ?

Comment: @QuangTV I have posted gradle file inside app module.

Comment: In your libs folder, can you post the name of files ?

Comment: @QuangTV libs folder is empty.

Comment: Did you update the sdk manager with the latest support library repository?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, thanks for replying. Yes it is installed. In android studio sdk manager I checked it is showing Android support repository version 25.0.0 and Android support library version 23.1.1.

Comment: have you run Android Studio in Administrator mode?

Comment: @Youngjae, I am login in windows 7 as administrator. Will it run android studio in admin mode or anything else is required?

Comment: try to right click the Android Studio icon and "Run as Administrator"

Comment: @Youngjae, It does not solve issue. Problem remain same after running in admin mode.

Comment: If I were you, I will try then, (1) comment out proguard line. (2) create new project and paste appcompat dependency line solely. (3) change SDK path to `C:\android-sdk` (4) totally remove Android Studio and SDK then reinstall them. At each point, must be clean-and-rebuild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved the problem. Issue was I have only added `proxy` for `http` and not `https` and after adding proxy for https it no longer get stuck in resolve dependencies and project is build successfully. Https proxy can be added in `gradle.properties` file in project root folder. Below lines are from `gradle.properties`to add both http and https proxy.

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=your proxy ip
systemProp.http.proxyPort=your proxy port
systemProp.https.proxyHost=your proxy ip
systemProp.https.proxyPort=your proxy port
```